Changing default scanned location for Windows fax and scan
I wanted to change the default scanned location of files thru a network drive by using windows fax and scan. Im having a hard time looking for a solution can anyone help?
I tried copying the right location in my network drive and put it into the routing scan but it says folder is not a valid server share
